# How to dynamically map inner type using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I defined the following four classes

```
   public class Source
    {
        public object Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Destination
    {
        public object Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class SourceDataType
    {
        //...
    }

    public class DestinationDataType
    {
        //...
    }
```

I configured the `Automapper` as follows:

```
        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>();
        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<SourceDataType, DestinationDataType>();
```

Then in my code, I create a `Source` object with `SourceDateType` value, and try to map it to a `Destination` object.

```
        var source = new Source { Value = new SourceDataType() };

        var destination = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Source, Destination>(source);

        Console.WriteLine(destination.GetType());
        Console.WriteLine(destination.Value.GetType());
```

The destination type is as expected. I was hoping `Automapper` would pick up on the mapping between the `SourceDataType` and `DestinationDataType` and map the `SourceDataType` instant to a `DestinationDataType` instant. However, the destination object was given a `SourceDataType` value instead.

I also tried `DynamicMap`, but achieved the same result.

```
        var destination = AutoMapper.Mapper.DynamicMap<Source, Destination>(source);
        var destination = AutoMapper.Mapper.DynamicMap<Destination>(source);
```

Is there a way to configure `Automapper` to dynamically map the inner classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solvable, although if more and more types got added to the mix, it will become unmaintainable and complex. Anyway, for your situation, this will work:

```
    [Test]
    public void CustomMapping()
    {
        //arrange
        Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
            .ForMember(d=>d.Value, opt=>opt.ResolveUsing(ResolveValue));
        Mapper.CreateMap<SourceDataType, DestinationDataType>();

        var source = new Source { Value = new SourceDataType() };

        //act
        var destination = Mapper.Map<Source, Destination>(source);

        //assert
        destination.Value.Should().Be.OfType<DestinationDataType>();
    }

    private object ResolveValue(ResolutionResult result)
    {
        var source = result.Context.SourceValue as Source;

        if (result.Context.IsSourceValueNull || source == null || !(source.Value is SourceDataType))
        {
            return null;
        }
        var sourceValue = source.Value as SourceDataType;

        return result.Context.Engine.Map<DestinationDataType>(sourceValue);
    }
```

Comment: You are right about the complexity increase with more types. The reason I have to use an `object` property is because I don't know the type at compile time. I guess i have to put all possible type combinations in the `ResoleValue` method.

Comment: @FrankLiu: this probably is going to be overkill. Maybe you can rethink the design with generics.

Comment: Yes, I will look into the generic `Source<T>` and `Destination<T>` solution. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

There's two problems here:

Firstly, you do not define any relationship between `SourceDataType` and `DestinationDataType` so there's no way for AutoMapper to know how to convert those types.

Secondly, the two properties are of type `object` and (as far as I know) AutoMapper won't convert based on the dynamic type.

You might be able to solve this issue by using a [Custom Type Converter](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-type-converters); however, I have reservations about this due to the property being of type `object`.

Anyway, you can try adding something based on the following mapping:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<object, object>().ConvertUsing(src =>
{
    if (src is SourceDataType)
        return new DestinationDataType(); // Put your conversion code here.
    else
        return src;
});
```

Like I said, I don't like this because `object` will match all property types.